# Jquery - a plugin that automatically animates the scrolling to the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, plugins, scroll

Im wondering if some of you knows a jquery plugin that automatically animates the scrolling to the bottom of the page. something that does this basically, but considering all the exceptions:

```
$bottom = 50;
function scroll() {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$bottom}, 4000, 'linear');
        $bottom = $bottom + 50;
        scroll();
}

scroll();
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is the one I used on a site recently.](http://www.sycha.com/jquery-smooth-scrolling-internal-anchor-links)

Just make the anchor point at the bottom of the page and you should be good!